# Rails Prawn converting my index table into a pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I am trying to create a .pdf that lists all of my projects(#index).

I found a great link-[How do generate PDFs in Rails with Prawn](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/10/13/how-to-generate-pdfs-in-rails-with-prawn/), however it was from 2008 and wanted me to use the prawnto plugin.

I am using Rails 3.2.13 so I decided to use the `gem prawn` and [RailsCast #153 PDFs with Prawn (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised), for reference. I was able to successfully get `Prawn` working in my:

```
    projects_controller

    def show
```

I am having trouble getting the .pdfs working in my `def index` though.

I tried to just mimic what I did, using the tutoiral for `def show`, for `def index` but am getting a routing error.

Here is my code thus far:

**Gemfile**

`gem 'prawn', '0.12.0'`

**projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

    def index 

    redirect_to action: :active, search =>params[:search]

    end

    def active

    @action = "active"
    ....
    ....  // search code
    ....  // kaminari code
    @projects = Project.order(sort_column + "" + sort_direction)

    respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render "index" }
    format.html { render "index" }
    format.pdf do
       pdf = ProjectAllPdf.new(@projects)
       send_data pdf.render, filename: "project_#{@project.product}.pdf",
                             type: "application/pdf",
                             disposition: "inline"
         end
       end
     end

     def show
       @project = Project.find(params[:id])

       respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json:@project }
       format.html # show.html.erb
       format.pdf do
         pdf = ProjectPdf.new(@project)
         send_data pdf.render, filename: "project_#{@project.product}.pdf",
                             type: "application/pdf",
                             disposition: "inline"
       end
      end
     end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<p><%= link_to "Printable Receipt (PDF)", project_path(@project, format: "pdf") %></p>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<p><%= link_to "Printable Receipt (PDF)", projects_path(@projects, format: "pdf") %></p>
```

I then formatted my file
**project_pdf.rb**

```
class ProjectPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(project)
    super(top_margin: 70)
    @project = project
    overview_print
  end

  def overview_print
    text "Project #{@project.product}", size: 24, style: :bold, align: :center
    move_down 30
    text "<b>Product:</b>  #{@project.product}", :inline_format => true
    move_down 8
    text "<b>Version Number:</b>  #{@project.version_number}", :inline_format => true
    move_down 8
    ....
    ....
  end
end
```

I then tried to mimic the last file to get #index working

**projectall_pdf.rb**

```
class ProjectAllPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(project)
    super(top_margin: 70)
    @project = project
    overview_print
  end

  def overview_print
    @projects.each do |project|
    text "<b>Product:</b>  #{@project.product}", :inline_format => true
    move_down 8
    text "<b>Version Number:</b>  #{@project.version_number}", :inline_format => true
    move_down 8
    ....
    ....
    end
    end
  end
```

Everything works great for `#show`. I just obviously have gotten myself mixed up on how to do the `#index` portions (def active, linking the .pdf in index.html.erb and projectall_pdf.rb)

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would post an answer to my question, hopefully it helps somebody.

I actually went ahead and used the `'gem prawnto_2', :require => "prawnto"`

It allowed me to use the `prawnto` and the prawnto tutorial with `Rails 3.2`

I then just created `(method).pdf.prawn` pages in my app/views/projects folder.

Then just add your custom pdf code to have you want to layout your pdf views.